# Creating a parsing dictionary to use with sys.argv

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a very basic script that utilises TkInter to draw lines based on user input. The user will execute the script through a command line, using parameters to determine the lines drawn.

The possible commands are:

```
(# signifies any whole number the user chooses)

P #   (selects a pen to draw with)
D     (pen down / starts drawing)
N #   (moves the pen north # increments)
E #   (moves the pen east # increments)
S #   (moves the pen south # increments)
W #   (moves the pen west # increments)
U     (pen up / stops drawing)
```

Example:

```
Parser.py P 3 D N 4 E 2 S 4 W 2 U
```

The above example will draw a tall rectangle.

I'm trying to create a basic parser for sys.argv that will run through all the arguments and execute methods from a dictionary based on said arguments and the order thereof.

Here is my code that runs through sys.argv and creates an array based on the arguments (I will be adding error-checking, so just assume a happy-day scenario for now):

```
class JoshSourceReader(object):
    """ responsibe for providing source text for parsing and drawing
        Initiates the Draw use-case.
        Links to a parser and passes the source text onwards """
    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = JoshParser()
        self.source = []
    def go(self):
        i = 1
        x = len(sys.argv)
        while i < x:
            if sys.argv[i]=="P":
                self.source.append("P " + str(sys.argv[i + 1]))
                i += 2
            elif sys.argv[i]=="D":
                self.source.append("D")
                i += 1
            elif sys.argv[i]=="N":
                self.source.append("N " + str(sys.argv[i + 1]))
                i += 2
            elif sys.argv[i]=="E":
                self.source.append("E " + str(sys.argv[i + 1]))
                i += 2
            elif sys.argv[i]=="S":
                self.source.append("S " + str(sys.argv[i + 1]))
                i += 2
            elif sys.argv[i]=="W":
                self.source.append("W " + str(sys.argv[i + 1]))
                i += 2
            elif sys.argv[i]=="U":
                self.source.append("U")
                i += 1
        self.parser.parse(self.source)
```

So the array that would be generated from my example above would look like this:

```
source=['P 3', 'D', 'N 4', 'E 2', 'S 4', 'W 2', 'U']
```

**So my question is this:** How can I create an efficient dictionary of methods that works with the above array and executes methods based on the array elements, one by one? I'm even starting to doubt if it's possible due to the fact that some methods will need properties passed (the number), and some won't. Anyone able to shed some light on this matter?

And please keep in mind that I'm *very* new to Python.

**EDIT:** I forgot one crucial piece of information. N, E, S, W all refer to the same method, but it takes a different argument each time. Here's the method (doesn't draw yet):

```
def drawLine(self, direction, distance):
    print("drawing line of length " + str(distance) + " at "
          + str(direction))
```

So if I were calling this method using "S 3", I would call it like so:

```
drawer.drawLine(180, 3)
```

And if I were to call it using "W 1", I would call it like so:

```
drawer.drawLine(270, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly tricky problem that is probably best solved by using a decent parsing framework. I usually recommend pyparsing for things like this. However, here's a solution that doesn't use any external frameworks.

It's somewhat ugly, but basically, it parses the input string, say 'P 1' into an operation and an integer. The dictionary contains the method to call, along with any additional parameters to be passed to the method (for the `drawLine()` case).

I've done this without using a class, but just adding `self` as the first parameter to everything should sort that out.

```
def selectPen(pen):
    print('called selectPen with pen', pen)

def penDown():
    print('called penDown')

def drawLine(direction, length):
    print('called drawLine with direction', direction, 'and length', length)

def penUp():
    print('called penUp')

def parseSource(source):
    tempSource = [op.split(' ') for op in source]
    parsedSource = []
    for op in tempSource:
        parsedOp = []
        for i, el in enumerate(op):
            if i == 0:
                parsedOp.append(el)
            else:
                try:
                    parsedOp.append(int(el))
                except ValueError:
                    parsedOp.append(el)
        parsedSource.append(tuple(parsedOp))

    return parsedSource

def dispatch(parsedSource):
    opDict = {'P':(selectPen,), 'D':(penDown,), 'N': (drawLine, 0), 'S':(drawLine, 180), 
    'E': (drawLine, 90), 'W': (drawLine, 270), 'U': (penUp,)}

    for op in parsedSource:
        methodName = op[0]
        methodToCall = opDict[methodName][0] 
        args = op[1:]
        if len(opDict[methodName])>1:
            args = opDict[methodName][1:] + args

        methodToCall(*args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    source=['P 3', 'D', 'N 4', 'E 2', 'S 4', 'W 2', 'U']
    parsedSource = parseSource(source)
    dispatch(parsedSource)
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. I think it'll will take me a while before I fully understand the code, but I aim to study it until I do. And I am using Python 3.x but easily changed the print statements myself.

Comment: I changed it anyway, for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can give default arguments to functions. So, just do something like this:

```
parsedict = {}
def func_P(times=0):
    #do whatever here
parsedict["P"] = func_P
#repeat however many times
for x in source:
    splitx = x.split(" ")
    if len(splitx) >= 2:
        parsedict[splitx[0]](splitx[1])
    else:
        parsedict[splitx[0]]()
```

If you need anything else, just comment. Should work, but I didn't test. You could also use [lambda functions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms), but you said you were new to Python, so I defined the function manually.

Comment: I forgot one critical piece of information that I've edited into the bottom of the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but an extended comment on your code.  I'm guessing that in the past you've worked in C or a C-like languge (Java, JavaScript, etc).  You're iterating through `sys.argv`  like this:

```
i = 1
x = len(sys.argv)
while i < x:
    if sys.argv[i]=="P":
```

In Python, there are simpler ways of iterating through a list. For example:

```
for arg in sys.argv:
    if arg == 'P':
```

Comment: I'm aware of that, but doing it in such a fashion would render the most important parts of my code broken. `self.source.append("P " + str(sys.argv[i + 1]))` would no longer work as `i` is no longer used to iterate through `sys.argv`.

Comment: Please use `for i, arg in enumerate(argv):` instead of either of the above solutions (or your own).

Comment: If you want to be more helpful, please explain your reasoning.  Thanks!

Comment: The `i,x in enumerate(iterable)` is the standard Python way of doing things. For one, it discourages in-place modification of the list. For another, it is more idiomatic in Python and requires less programmer time to parse while reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where a dictionary maps "commands" to the number of arguments they take:

```
argdict = {
    'P': 1,
    'D': 0,
    'N': 1,
    'E': 1,
    'S': 1,
    'W': 1,
    'U': 0
}

args = sys.argv[1:]
source = []

while args:
    command = [args.pop(0)]
    nargs = argdict[command[0]]
    command.extend(args[:nargs])
    args = args[nargs:]
    source.append(' '.join(command))

print source
```

Given your sample input, this would create a list that looked like:

```
['P 3', 'D', 'N 4', 'E 2', 'S 4', 'W 2', 'U']
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but is still very helpful code, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Painter(object):                                                            
    pencil_width = 1
    is_drawing = False

    def set_pencil(self, width=1):
        self.pencil_width = int(width)
    P = set_pencil

    def draw_north(self, blocks=1):
        if self.is_drawing:
            ...
    N = draw_north

    def process_command(self, str_):
        func_name = str_.split(' ')[0]
        args = str_.split(' ')[1:]
        try:
            func = getattr(self, func_name)
        except AttributeError:
            raise ValueError('Method %s does not exists'
                              % func_name)
        func(*args)


painter = Painter()
for command in source:
    painter.process_command(command)
```